# Throw within a Catch in threads

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, try-catch, throw

My problem is I cannot make the inner catch throw an exception.
Here I want ex to be thrown to the outer catch.

```
Runnable(){

public void run(){
try{
    try{
       }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Inner");
        throw ex; //I get an error here
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Outer");
}}
```

Error message: Unreported Exception must be caught, declared to be thrown

Comment: please post more info for your example, its just template

Comment: Is that all of the code?  What you've posted should not produce an uncaught `Exception` error.

Comment: Both e and ex are of type Exception. No specializations..

Answer (score 3):

Put the block in a function .....

```
private void myFunction() throws Exception {

    try{
       }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Inner");
        throw ex; //I get an error here
    }
}
```

Then call it from your code block

```
Runnable(){

public void run(){
    try{
        myFunction();
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Outer");
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to function just fine. Making nested try-catch blocks is considered bad practice.

```
public class Test implements Runnable {

public void run() {
    try {
        try {
            throw new IOException("bad"); //throw something here
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Inner");
            throw ex; 
        } finally  {

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Outer");
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test().run();
}

}

// PRINTS: 
// Inner
// Outer
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
Callable(){

public void call(){
try{
try{
   }catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Inner");
    throw ex; //I get an error here
}
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("Outer");
}}
```